# Stop items in a list view from being selected on right click

Tags: vb.net, listview, contextmenu, right-click, contextmenustrip

I have a ListView on a Windows Form in VB 2010.

I have set the `MultiSelect` property of the `ListView` to `False` so that only one item can be selected at any time.

I have configured a context menu for the `ListView` and it shows up correctly when the `ListView` is right clicked.

[Added a `ContextMenuStrip` control in the Designer and set the `ContextMenuStrip` property of the `ListView` to this.]

**Consider these 2 scenarios:**

1. A user right clicks on an item that is already selected in the `ListView`. Then the context menu is displayed and there are no issues.
2. A user right clicks on **an item other than the item that is already selected** in the `ListView`, Then before the context menu is displayed, the item that the user right clicked is selected.

**In scenario 2, I need to stop the item that the user right clicks on from being selected automatically. Need to context menu to be displayed but the item that was previously selected should remain selected.**

How can I achieve this?

I noticed that on the `ListView`'s `MouseDown` event, the `SelectedItems.Item(0).Index` property is still at the old index. However, on the `MouseUp` event, this property changes to the new index.

In the `MouseDown` event handler, or anywhere else, how can I stop the `SelectedItems` from changing? Or how can I change it back to the previous selected item (**without the user noticing it is being changed and then changed back**)?

I can catch a right click on the `MouseDown` or `MouseUp` using the code below. However, I am not sure what I need to put inside this condition to stop the `SelectedItems` from changing.

```
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
        ...
    End If
```

Note: I am able to use the following code for this. However, when I use this with scenario (2), it selects the item that the user right clicked on and then changes it back to the previous item and **this change back is seen by the user**. Therefore this solution cannot be used.

```
Dim intPrevSelectedIndex As Integer = -1
Dim boolCancel As Boolean = False
Private Sub ListView1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseDown
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 AndAlso e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
            boolCancel = True
            intPrevSelectedIndex = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Index
        End If
End Sub

Private Sub ListView1_MouseUp(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListView1.MouseUp
    If boolCancel Then
        lstWalkResults.Items(intPrevSelectedIndex).Selected = True
        boolCancel = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Please let me know any solutions you might have. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

In the code behind you should be able to handle the right click event. In that method you would display the context menu manually and then ignore the click event preventing the item from being selected.

```
If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then
    //display context menu because you're handling the click event manually.
    ...context menu code...
    Dim ee As New System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs(Forms.MouseButtons.None, e.Clicks, e.X, e.Y, e.Delta)
    e = ee
End If
```

Comment: `e.Handled = true` doesn't work. I get the error: `'Handled' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs'.`

Comment: A quick google search on MouseEventArgs turned up the solution.  See my revised answer.

Comment: I tried it. `Dim Hme As HandledMouseEventArgs = e` results in a an error: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs' to type 'System.Windows.Forms.HandledMouseEventArgs'.`

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried per my suggestion and what the error was.  The answer I provided should work, see this MSDN post showing exactly what I show you in my answer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.handledmouseeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The `HandledMouseEventArgs` class mentioned in the [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.handledmouseeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) provided is _to prevent the **`MouseWheel`** event from being sent to its parent container_. It doesn't work with the `MouseDown` event.

Comment: Ok after some research I have found that you cannot mark the event handled (in WPF you can) but instead you can ignore the event.  See my revised answer.

Comment: `e.Button = MouseButtons.None` doesn't work either. I get the error `Property 'Button' is 'ReadOnly'`

Comment: Thanks for the update. I tried the new code. It would only accept: `System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs(` **Windows** `.Forms.MouseButtons.Right, e.Clicks, e.X, e.Y, e.Delta) e = ee` but still it didn't stop the right click from triggering and the item in the listview from being selected. :(

Comment: I apologize, there was a typo in my answer. Please see the revised answer.

Comment: I tried this without adding the context menu code. `e.Button` gets set to `None`. However, the event still triggers. And the context menu appears as well.

Comment: This is the code i used: <br/>

`Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown` <br/>
        `If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Right Then` <br/>
            `Dim ee As New System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs(Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.None, e.Clicks, e.X, e.Y, e.Delta)` <br/>
            `e = ee` <br/>
`End If` <br/>
`End Sub`

Comment: @slayernoah If I'm not mistaken that's exactly the code I suggested you use. Why has this not been accepted as the answer?

Comment: I wanted to tell that the code that i used above (what you suggested) did not work unfortunately.

Comment: Then you need to provide the error you received or the problem you encountered.  Also please update your original question with what you tried and provide the code in it's entirety.